# Google's Place Details, Place Photos API: How do I request only photos that the owner has uploaded?

Tags: google-places-api

In the Google Maps Web UI, for any given place, I have filtering options for displaying subsets of images: "By owner" or "Vibe", and so on. See the example image below.

How do I, programmatically, achieve the same using Google's [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details) and/or [Place Photos](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/photos) APIs? E.g. how do I fetch only "By owner" images from a given place?

[image: Example]

Comment: It is not possible to query for photos. Please file a feedback request, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=789309, and post the link in a comment here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible using the current version of Google's Places API (Sept 1, 2021).

Many thanks to `jpoehnelt` for commenting and answering.